Error Installing griddb-c-client on macOS Ventura v13.0 with Homebrew
I am trying to install the griddb-c-client on my macOS Ventura v13.0 using Homebrew in order to set up GridDB on my device. However, I am encounter the following error:
Error: griddb/griddb-c-client/griddb-c-client: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
I tried installing it with homebrew with following command :
brew tap griddb/griddb-c-client
brew install griddb-c-client

But during the installation of griddb-c-client, I am facing that error.
I've tried the usual troubleshooting steps such as updating Homebrew with brew update and ensuring my system is up to date, but the issue persists.
Has anyone encountered this specific error before?
What might be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

Can you explain where you got the instructions on installing c client with brew? the github only shows to build from source: https://github.com/griddb/c_client

I am following https://github.com/griddb/homebrew-griddb-c-client.
